# iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus support is mandatory along with 64-bit and iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios8, 64-bit, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

As everyone know, App must support 64-bit and be built with the `iOS 8 SDK`. Does this mean app should have true `iPhone 6` and `iPhone 6 plus` support too?

I was searching all over but not able to find anything.

Please help me out.

FYI: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01192015a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Apple communication is about 32/64-bit Apps, iPhone6/plus support is not mentioned, so you can continue to send in review apps without 6/plus support

Answer (score 0):

Currently no, Apple normally gives a time period to allow for the transition. However for customer experience it is best to support new devices/technologies as soon as possible, from a user point of view, I am more likely to use an application if it does support the newer devices, if I own one, but this is my personal opinion.

Normally Apple will send out an email letting developers know that after a certain date, new apps and updates that do not add this support will not be accepted.